# How do I install M2Crypto on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, m2crypto

I'm trying to build and install M2Crypto on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  I downloaded and untarred M2Crypto-0.20.2.tar, and from the M2Crypto-0.20.2 directory I tried `python setup.py build`.  I got an error because I don't have swig.  So I ran `sudo apt-get install swig`.  Then I tried `python setup.py build` again and got:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -includeall -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_bio.i:64: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_rand.i:19: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_evp.i:156: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_dh.i:36: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_rsa.i:43: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_dsa.i:31: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_ssl.i:207: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_x509.i:313: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_pkcs7.i:42: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_pkcs7.i:42: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_util.i:9: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_ec.i:111: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
SWIG/_engine.i:162: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include -I/home/dspitzer/M2Crypto-0.20.2/SWIG -c SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.o -DTHREADING
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:126:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:757: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:781: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

...and so on.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this?

**Update:** I changed the title, since it didn't occur to me that M2Crypto would be a pre-build Ubuntu package.

Comment: That just didn't occur to me.  It worked just like it should.  If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably need to install the python development packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Better yet, don't bother building m2crypto yourself.  It's already [in the Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-m2crypto) as a fully supported package.  This way, you'll get automatic updates through the same means as the rest of your Ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto
```

Comment: Unfortunately, M2Crypto hasn't been ported to Python 3, yet :(

Answer (score 3):

do you have the python2.6-dev package installed?
this is the package that contains the Python.h file you are missing

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone will get openssl related errors, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```